# set path at multiple place inside same batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file

How to set path at one place in batch so that i can use it inside this batch everywhere , where i need it

example:

```
@echo off  
set "ROOT=somepath"

If Exist "%ROOT%\dc.xml" ( call "%ROOT%\dc.xml" )
timeout /T 7 
pause
```

I have a batch file, in this i have to find a file, if this file exists at some specified path then delete some files at the same path.

so i have to use same path over and over again to check,

Could anyone please let me the way how can i specify path at a place and use it in entire batch file by only specifying the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code...

> set ROOT=c:\testprogram
>
> set SRC_ROOT=%ROOT%\System\mySource

Please make sure..you need to use this without any space and also remove the quotes ["].

Hope this will help you.

thanks